# Get запрос на получение определенных данных с JSON

Tags: javascript

Пишу расширение на google хром, Скрипт должен работать следующим образом: открываю я страницу и скрипт начинает свою работу по считыванию всех id в data.user_chests. в Postam это все дело работает, но в расширении - нет.

manifest гугла:

```
 {
  "name":"War",
  "description":"...",
  "version":"1.0",
  "manifest_version":2,
  "content_scripts":[
    {
      "matches": ["https://wf.mail.ru/minigames/bpservices?"],
      "js" : ["script.js"],
      "run_at":"document_end"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "*://wf.mail.ru/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {  
        "default_icon": "icon.png", 
    }
}
```

Сам скрипт:

```
function wfopencase() {

var result = _.map(response.json().data.user_chests, data => data.id);
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
}

let wf_interval = setInterval(function() {
wfopencase();
}, 5000);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итоговый результат в postman, выводятся все id должным образом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иначе говоря как вот этот код с postman переконвертировать в код javascript:

```
var result = _.map(pm.response.json().data.user_chests, data => data.id);
pm.test(result, function() {
pm.environment.set("response", JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Comment: Вам надо подключить lodash.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko как это сделать

Comment: я скачал его но не знаю как его использовать

Comment: я сделал так но результата нету var _ = require('lodash');

var nn = _.map(response.json().data.user_chests, data => data.id);